# SHOW TABLES and DESCRIBE <table> Equivalents in Apache Pinot

Tags: apache-pinot

What are the equivalents for the `SHOW TABLES` and `DESCRIBE <table>` in Apache Pinot?

Basically, I just want to get a list of tables in the cluster and I want to be able to get the column names and their data types for a chosen table.

Answer (score 1):

As of Apache Pinot 0.11.x, it supports fetching schema only from its Controller APIs. See docs here https://docs.pinot.apache.org/basics/components/exploring-pinot#rest-api

Answer (score -1):

I think you can you use this to see all available commands:

[calcite dialect reference](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html)

> describe:
> DESCRIBE DATABASE databaseName
> |   DESCRIBE CATALOG [ databaseName . ] catalogName
> |   DESCRIBE SCHEMA [ [ databaseName . ] catalogName ] . schemaName
> |   DESCRIBE [ TABLE ] [ [ [ databaseName . ] catalogName . ] schemaName . ] tableName [ columnName ]
> |   DESCRIBE [ STATEMENT ] { query | insert | update | merge | delete }

Comment: Does Pinot use the same query language as Calcite? This does not seem to work. Additionally, as far as I am aware, Pinot does not include the concept of databases, it just has tables.